# Schema error for magento-mongodb integration

Tags: product, php-5.4, mongo

I have followed the [magento-mongo](http://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-mongo) github project to connect Magento with mongodb.

Everything seems to be perfect while integrating. But the problem is when I tried to change any configuration through admin panel, I tried to add a product through admin panel, then its showing some schema error in the `Cm/Mongo/Model/Indexer/Schema.php` file.

Can any one suggest me to solve this error? Here are I am posting the error code.

Error:

```
2014-03-17T09:41:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /var/www/mage2/app/code/community/Cm/Mongo/Model/Indexer/Schema.php on line 45
Trace: #0 /var/www/mage2/app/code/community/Cm/Mongo/Model/Indexer/Schema.php(45): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/var/www/mage2/...', 45, Array)
#1 /var/www/mage2/app/code/community/Cm/Mongo/Model/Indexer.php(116): Cm_Mongo_Model_Indexer_Schema->getEntityIndexers('catalog_product')
#2 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(331): Cm_Mongo_Model_Indexer->matchEntityAndType('catalog_product', 'mass_action')
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Index_Model_Process->indexEvents('catalog_product', 'mass_action')
#4 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php(324): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php(171): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->_runAll('indexEvents', Array)
#6 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(949): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->indexEvents('catalog_product', 'mass_action')
#7 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->reindexProductsMassAction(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer), 'reindexProducts...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /var/www/mage2/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('after_reindex_p...', Array)
#10 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(224): Mage::dispatchEvent('after_reindex_p...')
#11 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(249): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(178): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->massReindexAction()
#15 /var/www/mage2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massReindex')
```

Comment: Did you try raising an issue with the extension via github? https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-mongo/issues?page=1&state=open

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the extension on github there is a [fix](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-mongo/commit/c6ac4e77012fcd7a52649c9bedcc55943a453b15) that appears to solve a problem when trying to get an indexer.

This fix checks to see if there is an indexer node, before trying to work with it.

```
if ($this->getNode('indexer')) {
```

I would suggest trying the most recent version of this extension. If this does not work then try reporting an [issue directly on github](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-mongo/issues?page=1&state=open)